# Is there a tool that allows users to see their queries, but only their queries on Teradata?

Tags: teradata

My area supports three different business units on a single Teradata server.

Is there a way that I can allow the users of a business unit to see only their own queries, and to deny them access to the queries of other business unit?

Comment: Check the Viewpoint "My Queries" and "Query Groups" monitor portlets. They may provide the access you are looking for. If those are not flexible enough (too hard to manage in your environment) you could build your own application on top of the "monitor API" SQL functions to do the filtering.

Answer (score 0):

in Teradata ViewPoint there is a portlet to see your own (*) Queries running.

(*) => your own is limited to the Teradata Users you put to your ViewPoint Account in Profile. Any query from other users (regardless of Business Unit) can't be viewed with this.